# How to configure dependabot to check multiple files?

Tags: python, github, dependabot

The [official recommendation from pip-tools for cross-compilation](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#cross-environment-usage-of-requirementsinrequirementstxt-and-pip-compile) is:

> As the resulting requirements.txt can differ for each environment, users must execute pip-compile on each Python environment separately to generate a requirements.txt valid for each said environment.

I have multiple requirements files. One is called `requirements.txt`, another is `reqiurements-silicon.txt`

I have dependabot [configured](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file) on github, but how do I get it to check multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [unit tests for dependabot with `requirements.txt`](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/blob/47d28fe9faf92448630f0d62ee2de1f2194f8742/python/spec/dependabot/python/file_parser_spec.rb#L446), naming for `requirements.txt` variants has to include `requirements.txt` at the end - otherwise it will not be detected as a `requirements.txt`. I'd assume that is because there could be other `txt` files with the word `requirements` in them.

So change your file from `requirements-silicon.txt` to `silicon-requirements.txt`. This makes the ordering weird, but it at least gets picked up by Dependabot.

Comment: Thanks, but they are multiple files in the same directory. Requirements.txt, requirements-silicon.txt.

Comment: Ah that would be the issue then. Naming has to have `requirements.txt` at the end to be picked up. See my updated answer.

Comment: Can't propose an edit right now, but please include that your files are named `requirements.txt` and `requirements-silicon.txt` in the question, so that others can understand it more easily. Thanks!

Comment: So if they are "requirements.txt" and "silicon-requirements.txt" that might work?

Comment: Yeah tried it out and that worked for me. Also per the unit testing done in the dependabot project, that seems to be part of their specification (see my updated answer).